Let $A \subseteq [0, 1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ an infinite subset. Then $A$ has accumulation points.
Let $A \subseteq [0, 1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ an infinite subset. It is required to show that $A$ has accumulation points, but without using neither the completeness of $\mathbb{R}$ nor concepts like convergence, that is, with pure topological theory.
Define $X = [0, 1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$. To figure out the topological argument, we pick $x_1 = \frac{1}{2}$. Since $A$ is infinite, either $[0, x_1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ or $[x_1, 1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ has infinite many points. Define $A_1 = [a_1, b_1]$ to be one set containing infinite points of $A$. Picking $x_2$ to be the middle point of $A_1$ we can build $A_2 = [a_2, b_2]$ and iteratively find a decreasing sequence
$$\cdots \subset [a_{n+1}, b_{n+1}] \cap \mathbb{Q} \subset [a_{n}, b_{n}] \cap \mathbb{Q} \subset \cdots \subset [a_{2}, b_{2}] \cap \mathbb{Q} \subset [a_{1}, b_{1}] \cap \mathbb{Q} \subset A$$
where each $[a_{n}, b_{n}] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ has infinite points. So, to show that $A$ has accumulation points, I'll assume that $der_\tau(A) = \emptyset$, where $\tau$ is the induced topology of $X$ from the usual topology of $\mathbb{R}$. Thus, for each $x \in X$ there is $V \in \tau$ neighbourhood of $x$ such that
$$(V \cap A) \setminus \{x\} = \emptyset$$
In particular, for $\alpha = \sup\{a_n: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, there is WLOG $\epsilon > 0$ such that
$$(B_\epsilon(\alpha) \cap A) \setminus \{\alpha\} = \emptyset$$
Since $0 < |b_{n+1} - a_{n+1}| \le |b_{n} - a_{n}|$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there is some $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $0 < |b_{k} - a_{k}| < \epsilon$. Thus,
$$(B_\epsilon(\alpha) \cap [a_k, b_k] \cap \mathbb{Q}) \setminus \{\alpha\} \subseteq (B_\epsilon(\alpha) \cap A) \setminus \{\alpha\} = \emptyset$$
Since every $[a_k, b_k] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ has infinite many points of $A$, $(B_\epsilon(\alpha) \cap [a_k, b_k] \cap \mathbb{Q}) \setminus \{\alpha\} \neq \emptyset$ which is a contradiction.
I'm honestly not able to determine whether or not I'm using convergence concept. I can only use topological definitions and results, and real properties, since I've not seen characterization with sequences and things like that.

EDIT 1: One problem is that $\alpha$ may not be some $a_n$ and also how do I know that
$$\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} ([a_{n+1}, b_{n+1}] \cap \mathbb{Q}) \neq \emptyset$$

EDIT 2: For $X = [0, 1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$, if we define
$$\Omega = \bigcup_{x \in X} \Big \{B_\frac{1}{n}(x): n \in \mathbb{N} \Big\}$$
then $\Omega$ is a countable basis for $\tau|_{X}$. Therefore $X$ is second countable and by this result X is second countable then $A\subset X$ has an accumulation point for non-countable sets $A \subseteq X$, then $A$ has accumulation points. Is this result correct?

The fact that $[0,1]$ is compact is "pure topological theory".  Any infinite subset of a compact set has an accumulation point.

@RobertIsrael Thank you!! That is a very interesting result. Is it valid in general for topological spaces, or only for metric spaces?

It's valid for any compact topological space.

@RobertIsrael Does it really helps? What if the limit points are all irrationals? For $[0, 1]$ there is no problem, but for $X = [0, 1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$? The set $X$ is not compact with the induced topology...

It is indeed possible for all the limit points to be irrational. The question was a bit ambiguous in not specifying where the accumulation points are allowed to be.  If you want them to be in $A$, the answer is that it's not true.

It is basic courtesy in this site to accept and upvote answers which you have found to be of help. It is the only way you reward the user who has taken the time and effort to answer your query. You have not done so a few of your posts.

@Mr.GandalfSauron Yeah, I always upvote everything just after I understand every reasoning. Sorry mate

Standard proof by bisection:
For any subset $B$ of $A$, define the upper half of $B$, by
$$u(B) = \left\{x\in B\;\left|\; x\geq \frac{\sup{B}+\inf{B}}{2}\right.\right\}$$
and define the lower half as $l(B) = \mathscr{C}u(B)$.
Define $X\in\mathscr{P}(A)^{\mathbb{N}}$ as follows
$$\begin{cases}
X_0 = A,\\
X_{n+1} = 
\begin{cases}
u(X_n), & \aleph(u(X_n))\geq \aleph_0,\\
l(X_n), & \aleph(u(X_n))<\aleph_0.
\end{cases}
\end{cases}$$
then $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}, \aleph(X_n)\geq \aleph_0$. Indeed, it is indubitably true for $n=0$. Now, asume true for $n$, then we have two cases
case 1. $\aleph(u(X_n))\geq \aleph_0$. In this case, $X_{n+1} = u(X_n)$ and thus it has infinite cardinality by assumption.
case 2. $\aleph(u(X_n))< \aleph_0$. In this case, since $X_n = u(X_n) \cup l(X_n)$, then one has $\aleph(X_n) \leq \aleph(u(X_n)) + \aleph(l(X_n))$, but, since $u(X_n)$ is finite, then if $l(X_n)$ were finite, we would have that $X_n$ is finite, contradicting our inductive hypothesis, thus $l(X_n)$ is infinite. We conclude then that $X_{n+1}$ is infinite.
We conclude that $X_n$ is always infinite. furthermore, $X_{n+1}\subseteq X_n$. Let $x\in \bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}} X_n$ (in fact, there should be only one such point). You should be able to show that $x$ is a limit point.

I made a serious blunder on my answer an it is wrong: we don't know if $\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}}X_n \neq \emptyset$. For a counterexample, let $x_n\to \sqrt{2}/2$. Then, if $A = {x_n\mid n\in\mathbb{N}}$, then clearly $\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}}X_n = \emptyset$.
Please un-accept this answer.
The real proof comes from the fact that every countably infinite subset of a countably compact space has at least one closure point (in fact, this characterizes countable compactness).
I apologice for this mistake.
